# How to customize Laravel Form class?

Tags: forms, laravel

Is there a way to customize any of Laravel's core classes, specifically the Form class? I'm looking to customize the `Form::text()` and `Form::textarea()` so it will contain some default classes which I always use in my fields.

I used to do this a lot in CI and was wondering if Laravel allows this as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Laravel's built in form macro.

http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros

For example.

```
Form::macro('customField', function()
{
  return '<input type="text" class="macro-some-class">';
});
```

and call the macro

```
echo Form::customField();
```

or

```
{{Form::customField()}}
```

Comment: `Form::macro()` looks like it's just what I need. But for the sake of world peace, isn't there some way to extend core Laravel classes to fit our specific needs?

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter in Form::text() accept an array of attributes you wish to pass to the text field, e.g.,

```
Form::text('name', 'Enter your name', array('class' => 'large', 'title' => 'Enter your full name'));
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. No need for a macro